# Why must a call hs_init from a shared library (not statically linked)

Tags: haskell, ffi

I wrote a simple haskell module that I can convert into a shared library:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Safe where

import Foreign.C.Types

add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add p q = p + q

hs_add :: CInt -> CInt -> CInt
hs_add a b = fromIntegral (add (fromIntegral a) (fromIntegral b))

foreign export ccall hs_add :: CInt -> CInt -> CInt
```

with the command

```
ghc -O2 -dynamic -shared -fPIC -o libAdd.so Add.hs -lHSrts-ghc8.2.2
```

The following program works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <HsFFI.h>

#define _LIB_INIT

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void* handle;

    static char *argv_N[] = { NULL }, **argv_ = argv_N;
    static int argc_ = 0;

    handle = dlopen("./libAdd.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return 12;
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Successfully loaded library\n");

#ifdef _LIB_INIT
    void (*hs_init_l)(int *argc, char **argv[]) = dlsym(handle, "hs_init");
    hs_init_l(&argc_, &argv_);
#else
    hs_init(&argc_, &argv_);
#endif

    int (*hs_add)(int a, int b) = dlsym(handle, "hs_add");
    if (!hs_add)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to load func : %s\n", dlerror());
        return 3;
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Successfully loaded function\n");

    int a=8, b=12;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, hs_add(a, b));

    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it with

```
ghc --make -no-hs-main -optc-O test.c -o test
```

However, if I remove the line defining `_LIB_INIT`, I get

```
Successfully loaded library
Successfully loaded function
newBoundTask: RTS is not initialised; call hs_init() first
```

In other words, if I call `hs_init` from the shared library it works, but if I call it the statically linked copy, the `hs_add` function doesn't recognize it.

What is the difference between these?

Comment: You could use flag `-dynamic` when compiling the main executable.

Comment: At a guess: the RTS uses global variables, `hs_init` initializes them, and the statically linked and dynamically linked copies of the RTS have independent storage spaces for these globals.